# is object eligible for garbage collection while dodeploy war in jboss?

Tags: java, jboss

As I know multiple war is deployed on a server, so every time restarting server is not a good option.so I just do deploy that particular war which have any version updates. but after some days it throws heap space issues. and if I didn't do dodeploy and restart server while updating version. it does not throw heap space issue.

so I have doubt with it.

1)what does it do internally while do deploy war in jboss7?

2) is it not do garbage collection for all objects of previous war?

3) is there any extra settings required to work perfect while do deploying?

this question may be very silly..but It is very serious issue for me on production server.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOME's triggered by redeploying WAR files is a classic symptom of a classloader leak:

- There are apparently classloader leaks in JBoss 7.
- There are things that your code is doing that could result in a classloader leak.

Unfortunately, these leaks can be difficult to track down and cure, and it is often more practical to shutdown and restart the container.

References:

- [Classloader leaks: the dreaded "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" exception](http://frankkieviet.blogspot.com.au/2006/10/classloader-leaks-dreaded-permgen-space.html)
- [How to fix the dreaded "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" exception](http://frankkieviet.blogspot.com.au/2006/10/how-to-fix-dreaded-permgen-space.html)
- [ClassLoader leaks in AS7](https://community.jboss.org/message/716191)
- [JBoss 7, java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646483/jboss-7-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space)

Comment: thanks this links help me a lot :) and also I found jboss stopped in between execution of queries of program..so I have to do `ctrl+c` once and the application will execute further queries..do you have any idea about it? I am using mostly criteria of hibernate in business logic.

Comment: Sorry.  No idea about that.  Ask it as a new Question ... and make sure you provide all relevant details.