# Jboss 4.2.2 to Jboss 7.1.1 Migration issue

Tags: java, jboss

In my application i am using Struts,Spring,Hibernate and Axis2 webservice.Currently my application is working fine on Jboss4.2.2.
And i am migrating it on JBoss7.1.1 facing some problems.
Following is error comes when I start jboss7.1.1 actually it shows that my war "mydocs.war" is deployed. but when i hits my loginPage it give me following error.

```
 11:31:01,470 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 38110ms - Started 828 of 912 services (83 services are passive or on-demand)
11:31:01,486 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "mydocs.war"
11:49:58,177 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Hibernate: select this_.id as id127_0_, this_.constant_name as constant2_127_0_, this_.constant_value as constant3_127_0_, this_.description as descript4_127_0_ from APPLICATION_CONSTANTS this_ where this_.constant_name=?

11:49:59,037 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Failed to define class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration in Module "org.jboss.as.web:main" from local module loader @145c859 (roots: D:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.initializeParser(Compiler.java:685) [jasper-jdt-7.0.3.Final.jar:]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.<init>(Compiler.java:283) [jasper-jdt-7.0.3.Final.jar:]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.<init>(Compiler.java:159) [jasper-jdt-7.0.3.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:430) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:607) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:312) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:840) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:622) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]

11:49:59,724 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/mydocs].[jsp]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/ast/TypeDeclaration
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.initializeParser(Compiler.java:685) [jasper-jdt-7.0.3.Final.jar:]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.<init>(Compiler.java:283) [jasper-jdt-7.0.3.Final.jar:]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.<init>(Compiler.java:159) [jasper-jdt-7.0.3.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:430) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:607) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:312) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:840) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:622) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:560) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1085) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:398) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:241) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.mydocs.webapp.filter.MyDocsBrandFilter.doFilterInternal(MyDocsBrandFilter.java:130) [classes:]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:77) [spring.jar:2.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.parsePage(PageFilter.java:118) [sitemesh-2.2.1.jar:]
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:52) [sitemesh-2.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:375) [urlrewrite-3.0-beta.jar:3.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.mydocs.webapp.filter.GZIPFilter.doFilterInternal(GZIPFilter.java:31) [classes:]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:77) [spring.jar:2.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125) [displaytag-1.1.jar:1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.mydocs.webapp.filter.LocaleFilter.doFilterInternal(LocaleFilter.java:55) [classes:]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:77) [spring.jar:2.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:174) [spring.jar:2.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:77) [spring.jar:2.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:264) [acegi-security-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107) [acegi-security-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72) [acegi-security-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274) [acegi-security-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:110) [acegi-security-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274) [acegi-security-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125) [acegi-security-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274) [acegi-security-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:135) [acegi-security-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274) [acegi-security-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.acegisecurity.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:81) [acegi-security-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274) [acegi-security-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:217) [acegi-security-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274) [acegi-security-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at com.mydocs.webapp.filter.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:143) [classes:]
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274) [acegi-security-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:193) [acegi-security-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274) [acegi-security-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:148) [acegi-security-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98) [acegi-security-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:78) [spring.jar:2.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:77) [spring.jar:2.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JBoss 7, java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646483/jboss-7-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space)

Answer (score 0):

You get an `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646483/jboss-7-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space) for more details.